# Why is call to jQuery UI button breaking my pages scripts?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, button

## What I'm doing:

I'm using a three jQuery UI widgets plus a separate jQuery based navigation menu.

You can see the three UI widgets working together here:

http://www.dominornovus.com/jquery-test-environment/

(link features datepicker, selectmenu and button jQuery UI widgets)

## The problem:

When I copy my working code to another website, the call to the jQuery UI button randomly breaks all jQuery on my page (including the separate jQuery based navigation menu):

http://www.dominornovus.com/killyliss-country-house/test/

The only difference between the pages found at the two links I've provided is the jQuery based navigation menu.

**Please note that even when I delete all code relating to the navigation menu, the call to the button UI widget still breaks jQuery on my page.**

## My question

Can anyone deduce from the two pages what difference exists and why one page fails on the button UI call but the other page doesn't?

**I can't find any discernible difference between the two pages and yet they behave differently. One breaks; the other doesn't.**

Comment: you are having an error in line 5 in http://www.dominornovus.com/killyliss-country-house/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/jquery.ui.button.min.js?ver=1.8.20 try to solve that because the script stop. sorry for the language

Comment: The two pages aren't equal regarding to jQuery / jQuery-UI code.

Comment: @DamianSIlvera Does this mean my jquery.ui.button.js file is broken or am I calling it wrong? See my code here: http://pastebin.com/jU309mPh

Comment: @marcosfromero How did you come to that conclusion? What are you using to read the jQuery code for each page?

Comment: When you run the code the message "this.element.propAttr is not a function in line 5" appears. May be you did something wrong in the code and that is why its not working. (When a error appear the script stop sorry for bad language)

Comment: @DamianSIlvera Your language is not a problem. jquery.ui.button.js is a standard file bundled with WordPress so it should be functionally correct. I'm guessing the problem is related to the fact that I'm calling jQuery's library from two different sources: once from WordPress and once from Google. I think the two different versions mights be conflicting or incompatible.

Comment: @DamianSIlvera: I just saw the source code of the two HTML pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further research, this turned out to be a WordPress issue so I posted the issue to WordPress Answers instead.

Simply put, I was enqueueing jQuery twice.

Here's my final working code (added to theme's function.php file):

```
    //https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/64062/cannot-enqueue-jquery-correctly-using-google-cdn
    //http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#Load_a_default_WordPress_script_from_a_non-default_location

    function my_scripts_method() {
        wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
        wp_register_script( 'jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.12/jquery.min.js');
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'uicss', '(path_ to_script_location)/my-custom-style.css' );    
        wp_enqueue_script( 'uisel', 'http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/branches/labs/selectmenu/ui.selectmenu.js' );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'uicss2', 'http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/branches/labs/selectmenu/ui.selectmenu.css' );
    }    

    //add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method'); // selectmenu would not work targeting wp_enqueue_scripts
    add_action('wp_head', 'my_scripts_method'); //use wp_head instead
```

The WordPress Answers thread can be read here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/64062/cannot-enqueue-jquery-correctly-using-google-cdn

After some time, I've figured out how to successfully apply the selectmenu widget to WordPress.

WordPress installations come complete with a bundle of jQuery scripts.

The fnagel selectmenu will not work the default bundle of jquery and jquery-ui scripts and instead has to be referenced externally using Google CDN.

I had to deregister the default local jQuery library for WordPress, enqueue the Google CDN and then enqueue the selectmenu script and CSS.